# Error message running C in linux account but not on mac terminal

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I would like to know where and why did my code go wrong that it caused an error message like the one shown below to pop up? Because compiling the C code on my terminal worked fine, however it was different in linux, so I was wondering where did it go wrong. The error happens when I enter "-1" to exit my purchase function. Thank you so much for your time and pointing out my mistakes!

```
int purchase(void){
        char menu_code[6]; //user input meal code   
        FILE *fptr; //flie pointer for receipt text file        
        FILE *tfptr; //flie pointer for trans text file 
        FILE *mfptr; //flie pointer for combo text file
        FILE *afptr; //flie pointer for addon text file
        int quantity=0, itemFound=0,total_quantity=0;   
        float total=0, grand_total=0;
        unsigned int combo_trans=0, ala_trans=0, i;
        struct Meal meal;

        printf("Please enter a menu code (-1 to exit purchase). Example: C0001.\n");
        scanf("%s", menu_code);

        fptr = fopen("receipt.txt", "w"); //clear file before appending for each purchase       
        while(strcmp(menu_code, "-1") != 0)//while loop to compare the input with sentinel value
        {
            mfptr = fopen("combo.txt", "r");//command to open a specific file
            while(!feof(mfptr))
            {
                fscanf(mfptr, "%5[^:]:%[^:]:%f:%[^\n]\n", meal.mcode, meal.name, &meal.price, meal.description);    
                if(strcmp(menu_code, meal.mcode) == 0)
                {
                    printf("Enter the quantity of the meal: ");
                    scanf("%d",&quantity);          
                    quantity = (quantity <= 0) ? 0 : quantity; //accepting valid values for quantity                          
                    total = meal.price * quantity;
                    grand_total += total;    
                    total_quantity += quantity;                         
                    itemFound ++;
                    combo_trans++;                      
                    print_order(quantity, meal.name, meal.price, grand_total); 

                    tfptr = fopen("trans.txt", "a+");
                    fprintf(tfptr, "%u:%u:%.2f\n", quantity, 0, total); 
                    fclose(tfptr);
                    fptr = fopen("receipt.txt", "a+");
                    fprintf(fptr, "%-15u%-34s%-17.2f\n", quantity, meal.name, meal.price*quantity);
                    fclose(fptr);

                }
            }fclose(mfptr);//closes the file after execution

            if(itemFound == 0)//start of if statement
            {
                afptr = fopen("addon.txt", "r");
                while(!feof(afptr))
                {
                    fscanf(afptr, "%5[^:]:%[^:]:%f:%[^\n]\n", meal.mcode, meal.name, &meal.price, meal.description);  
                    if(strcmp(menu_code, meal.mcode) == 0)
                    {
                       printf("Enter the quantity of the meal: ");
                       scanf("%d",&quantity);          
                       quantity = (quantity <= 0) ? 0 : quantity;                             
                       total = meal.price * quantity;
                       grand_total += total;
                       total_quantity += quantity;                                 
                       itemFound ++;
                       ala_trans++;                     
                       print_order(quantity, meal.name, meal.price, grand_total); 

                       tfptr = fopen("trans.txt", "a+");
                       fprintf(tfptr, "%u:%u:%.2f\n", 0, quantity, total); 
                       fclose(tfptr);
                       fptr = fopen("receipt.txt", "a+");
                       fprintf(fptr, "%-15u%-34s%-17.2f\n", quantity, meal.name, meal.price*quantity);
                       fclose(fptr);
                    }
                }fclose(afptr);
            }//end of if statement
            if(itemFound == 0){
                printf("Invalid menu code!\n");
            }
            itemFound = 0;
            printf("Please enter a menu code (-1 to exit purchase). Example: C0001.\n");
            scanf("%s", menu_code);
        };//end of while loop
        fclose(fptr);
        print_receipt(ala_trans, combo_trans, total_quantity, grand_total);
        order();
        return 0;
    }
```

The error:

```
*** glibc detected *** ./a.out: double free or corruption (out): 0x09c392d8 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/libc.so.6(+0x70b81)[0xb75fbb81]
/lib/libc.so.6(+0x732d8)[0xb75fe2d8]
/lib/libc.so.6(fclose+0x14a)[0xb75eb6fa]
./a.out[0x804a4d6]
./a.out[0x804a693]
./a.out[0x804879f]
/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe6)[0xb75a1d36]
./a.out[0x8048701]
======= Memory map: ========
08048000-0804c000 r-xp 00000000 fd:02 12853280                           /home/0333120/Assignment/a.out
0804c000-0804d000 rw-p 00003000 fd:02 12853280                           /home/0333120/Assignment/a.out
09c39000-09c5a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
b7567000-b7584000 r-xp 00000000 fd:02 12314805                           /lib/libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
b7584000-b7585000 rw-p 0001d000 fd:02 12314805                           /lib/libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
b758a000-b758b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b758b000-b771b000 r-xp 00000000 fd:02 12314671                           /lib/libc-2.12.so
b771b000-b771c000 ---p 00190000 fd:02 12314671                           /lib/libc-2.12.so
b771c000-b771e000 r--p 00190000 fd:02 12314671                           /lib/libc-2.12.so
b771e000-b771f000 rw-p 00192000 fd:02 12314671                           /lib/libc-2.12.so
b771f000-b7722000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b7724000-b7728000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b7728000-b7746000 r-xp 00000000 fd:02 12314649                           /lib/ld-2.12.so
b7746000-b7747000 r--p 0001d000 fd:02 12314649                           /lib/ld-2.12.so
b7747000-b7748000 rw-p 0001e000 fd:02 12314649                           /lib/ld-2.12.so
b7748000-b7749000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                                  [vdso]
bfec9000-bfede000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [stack]
Aborted
```

Comment: Could you clarify your compiling process? Did you compile and run successfully with macOS and run into trouble compiling and running with Linux? Note that the binary you compiled in macOS won't work on Linux.

Comment: Your code contains several bugs. Please read [mcve].

Comment: I compile it successfully with macOS and linux.But I had trouble running it on linux while it works perfectly find on macOS. So I was wondering which part caused this error to happen while running in linux. Thanks!

Comment: I am not facing any problem during compilation.I am getting this error after my program runs successfully(i.e after I enter "-1" in my purchase function).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error was caused by run time issue I suppose (after a little bit of research, bear in mind, I just started learning C just a few weeks ago and I'm still new with it). There were 2 files opened (receipt and trans), but either one wasn't logically closed. Hence causing the program to crash and fail in between my purchase function. So do check where to place your file openings and closings properly.

There is no point in opening the file to write (receipt.txt) and closing it only in the end. So, I changed it to close right after writing it to overwrite the file with a blank state each time the function is called.